# what is the use of \ operator inside a list in python?

Tags: python

What is the use of \ in python?
Example, I saw the following codes"

```
    data_idxs = [(self.entity_idxs[data[i][0]], self.relation_idxs[data[i][1]], \
                  self.entity_idxs[data[i][2]]) for i in range(len(data))]
```

or

```
    self.relations = self.train_relations + [i for i in self.valid_relations \
            if i not in self.train_relations] + [i for i in self.test_relations \
            if i not in self.train_relations]
```

I guess you write \ when you want to have your code continue in a new line? But I also saw that when you have a lot of parameter in a method definition, you can have new line without using .

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length

Comment: This is a pointless use of the line-continuation character (it isn't acting as an operator in this case). You can just remove it, it is unecessary inside parentheses

Comment: [Line joining in doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I guess you write \ when you want to have your code continue in a new line?

Yes. That's all it means.

In these cases it's not actually needed though because line continuation is implied by brackets.